# Localizable.strings corrupted?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to include the internationalization of my application, and only for testing purposes I added a simple line in the file Localizable.string.

This is my whole file:

> "Test locale" = "Test locale"

And when I try run my application I get this error:

> Localizable.strings:0: error: validation failed: The data couldn’t be
> read because it has been corrupted.

I've tried changing the "Text Encoding" to UTF-16 but nothing resolved.

Comment: here is a library that might help you to localize project  https://github.com/dipkasyap/DGLocalization

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If this is your whole file, add a semicolon at the end. Change it to:

> "Test locale" = "Test locale"**;**

Comment: Learning iOS first time with swift comming from Android, this is actually a really annoying mistake...

Answer (score 45):

To get more detailed informations you can use the Property List utility from the command line:

```
plutil -lint <your_strings_file>.strings
```

the  `-lint` switch is for checking the syntax. If you have an error you'll get line number and more informations, and in general better directions on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Way too big of a file to check by hand.

Comment: Is there a way to integrate this command into the Xcode build ?

Comment: Never tried, but this is what you can try: you can add a run script phase in "build phases" and, in this phase, call a script that checks all of your .strings files. You can drag the script phase on top of the others (or drag the others down) in order to execute tour script pre-build. it you set XCode -> Preferences -> Building -> Build options "Continue building after errors" then the build stops if the script fails.

Comment: In order to stop the process and fail the build you can simply terminate your script with an exit code other than zero. As an example if something goes wrong you can use "exit 1".

Comment: If `plutil -lint` reports "OK", does not necssarily mean that there are no errors. For example I had the problem that there were unescaped quotation marks within my strings, but the Linter said the file was OK. So I would say  you can trust `plutil -lint` if it reports errors but not if it reports OK.

Comment: It's sickening that Xcode itself doesn't show any line numberings for these errors and you have to run an external tool :/

Answer (score 7):

You can verify your Localizable.strings file with this script:

https://github.com/dcordero/Rubustrings

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was like this:

```
/* Comment for Very Long Sentence */
"Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence " =;
"Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence Very Long Sentence ";
```

(Notice the ' **= ;** ' instead of ' **=** ' at the end of the first line)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was brackets inside string — I needed to add slash before \".

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little script to check whole folders .strings files using plutil.

https://github.com/CarlesEstevadeordal/check_strings

Comment: A simple command is enough: `find . -name '*.strings' -exec plutil -lint {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this:

1. Semicolon is missing at the end.
2. Multiple semicolons at the end.
3. " within the message which should be escaped by \".
4. Extra character after semicolon.
5. Invalid white space in the file.
6. Other invalid characters in the file.
7. Merge conflict characters in the file!

`<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======` and `>>>>>>>`.

Please note that `plutil -lint Localizable.strings` returned `OK` for point-2 & 7!